# Filter datagrid based on arraycollection data in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

I have

1. One arraycollection called **ordersAC** which contains number of
   dynamic data like **orderId**.
2. Another arraycollection is the dataprovider of the datagrid called
   **ordersRecordAC**, Contains (orderId, orderTitle, orderDescription, price).

---

DataGrid contains 4 columns:

```
No.   OrderTitle   OrderDescription   Price
```

Now, DataGrid has 100 record. And I want to filter DataGrid using first arraycollection(ordersAC) which is dynamically changed every time.

like: **ordersAC** has 5 `orderId` 1521, 2154, 2233, 5484, 2351

then in DataGrid display only 5 records depend on `orderId`.

I tried following ways but didn't work:

```
private function onSearchRecordClick(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var orderAC:ArrayCollection = ordersGridId.orderAC;
    for(var i:int = 0; i<ordersRecordAC.length-1;i++)
    {
        orderAC.filterFunction = filterRows; 

        function filterRows(item1:Object):Boolean 
        {
            if(item1.orderId == ordersRecordAC[i])
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    orderAC.refresh();
}

<mx:DataGrid id="ordersGridId" lockedColumnCount="5" dataProvider="{orderAC}" sortableColumns="true">
```

Hope Understand my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following w/ your code.

```
private var orderAC:ArrayCollection; // assign this somewhere else

private function onSearchRecordClick(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  if(!orderAC.filterFunction)
    orderAC.filterFunction = filterRows; 
  orderAC.refresh();
}

private function filterRows(item1:Object):Boolean 
{
  for(var i:int = 0;i < ordersRecordAC.length;i++)
  {
    if(item1.orderId == ordersRecordAC[i])
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```